# Overriding "Method Not Found" Exception in Fitnesse

Tags: c#, fitnesse

I am trying to make a custom Exception message in Fitnesse that overrides the default 'Method Not Found' exception so that it prints out a message such as "This method does not exist. Available methods are ..."

I have found ways to print custom exception messages that happen within the C# fixture as explained [here](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.SliM.ExceptionHandling), but I have not found any examples of how to do this with Method Not Found, as this occurs within Fitnesse, rather than the C# fixture.

Is doing this even possible, and if so, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds more like a feature to be added to FitNesse rather than something you can do in your fixture currently.  There is no mechanism in the code for this right now.

Feel free to post a issue to https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse and you are welcome to contribute a solution.  Now the solution will probably need to be done two ways, as FitSharp doing FitLibrary would need to work one way and the Slim implementation would be different.

I like the idea.